# AWS CDK, how to correctly deal with stateful resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a stack that includes an ECR, an RDS db, and a service launched on ECS that pulls an image from the ECR, and needs to talk to the RDS db.  My ECR and RDS interface with other outside-of-AWS things, e.g. my CI/CD process that pushes images to ECR - so I need to be able to reference these resources somehow.

I may need to periodically update small things, such as the security groups on the ECS.

My current setup and issue: I have given my ECR and RDS a fixed name, so that I can reference these things externally.  However, CloudFormation really wants to "recreate" these resources after the first deployment, even though they already exist.  So, it complains when I try to deploy my stack, even though my diff shows "no changes".  I DO NOT want to destroy my repo or my database and recreate them.

What is the AWS expected way to deal with this sort of situation?  I can't seem to find any good documentation on it.  My options seem to be to 1) accept that these resources get recreated, and to have a complex out-of-CDK process to re-setup and copy the old resources to the new resources, and to manage the changing resource names 2) completely separate each construct into its own "stack", and just look up everything by name.  Both of these seem like hacks to me.  However, my stack of "backend web service talks to database" seems like such a common use case, that I find it difficult to believe that the expected solution is the hacky solution.  Is there an elegant solution for this use case?

Comment: I think that [this is related](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6762).  I'm not tied to any particular deployment strategy, so maybe the workarounds there don't apply to me.